# Angular is null when using Typescript 1.5 and require

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to use AngularJS 1.4.3 with TypeScript 1.5

My typescript file is

```
/// <reference path="typings/angular/angular" />
/// <reference path="controllers/LoginController" />

import * as angular from 'angular';
import { LoginController } from './controllers/LoginController';

if (angular)
    console.log('angular is not null!');
else
    console.log('angular is null!');

console.log('version:' + angular.version);

var myApp = angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('LoginController', LoginController);
```

which is converted to the following JS

```
/// <reference path="typings/angular/angular" />
/// <reference path="controllers/LoginController" />
define(["require", "exports", 'angular', './controllers/LoginController'], function (require, exports, angular, LoginController_1) {
    if (angular)
        console.log('angular is not null!');
    else
        console.log('angular is null!');
    console.log('version:' + angular.version);
    var myApp = angular.module('app', [])
        .controller('LoginController', LoginController_1.LoginController);
});
//# sourceMappingURL=test.js.map
```

However when it is run in the browser "angular" is undefined.   If I type "angular" into the console it finds angular, and requirejs is loading angular correctly (as seen in the network trace and the fact angular works from the console).

I tried using

```
import angular from 'angular';
```

But I visual studio 2015 gives me the error

```
Module 'angular' has no default export
```

I'm nearly certain the error is with the import statement, just can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Create a require config file and make a shim for angular and export it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a require config file and add a shim for angular and exports it.

```js
require.config({
    baseUrl: "somepath/scripts",
    paths: {
        "angular": "libraries/angular",
        "angular-resource": "libraries/angular-resource",
    },
    shim: {
        "angular": {
            exports: "angular"
        },
        "angular-resource": {
            deps: ["angular"]
        },
    }
});
```